# How do MemReq and MemResp exactly work in RoccIO - RISCV

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv, chisel

I'm trying to figure out how can I read from and write to memory in RISCV when I'm using RoCCIO. But I couldn't clearly get what is happening. Especially how can I address the memory or how should I work with memory `tag`. 
Are there any resources that I can find how I can transfer data between Rocket core and my Accelerator?

In the `uncore/src/main/scala/consts.scala` path they have mentioned different type of memory `cmd`. But what else?

For example I want to pass starting address of an array and number of elements that I plan to fetch into the accelerator and then start fetching them. What signalling should I use?

Thanks

Comment: You should look at the provided documentation on Rocket-Chip and the RoCC interface found at (http://riscv.org/workshop-jan2015/riscv-rocket-chip-tutorial-bootcamp-jan2015.pdf) and (http://riscv.org/workshop-jan2015.html).  They can point you to code examples.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I have seen all their documentation and slides and even if lecture slides of CS 250 course in Berkeley but I couldn't find answer of my questions about transferring data

Comment: Did you look at the provided SHA3 example accelerator? https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocc-template/tree/sha3

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. I try to find out what is happening in `ctrl` module but I couldn't find out clearly that's why I made this Question

Answer (score 2):

Within the RoCC interface, the `mem` field is a connection to the L1 cache.  The `dmem` field is a connection to the L2 cache. Which one you want to use depends upon the memory bandwidth requirements of your accelerator.

Rocket and the RoCC accelerator can either share data through the caches (remember to use a `fence` instruction on the Rocket core so the memory ordering is correct) or you can directly give data to Rocket through the `resp` field in the RoCCIO.

The L1 cache's IO can be found in Rocket's (https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket/blob/master/src/main/scala/nbdcache.scala) whereas the L2 IO can be found in the uncore's (https://github.com/ucb-bar/uncore/blob/master/src/main/scala/tilelink.scala).

Although I don't know which memory `tag` you are referring to, typically the `tag` is passed through the memory system and returned to you with the response untouched (if you have multiple requests inflight, this returning tag helps you identify which is which).

I suspect if you want to fetch an array of data, you will need a state machine to request each individual address in your accelerator. Unless you go through the L2 cache interface, in which case I believe it comes in cache-line sizes.

Comment: Thanks Chris!, your post was so helpful for me. I should read more and may ask questions again!